# VBA code to generate Pivot Table in Excel 2010

Tags: excel, vba, pivot-table

I have a workbook which will be updated every week. the worksheet (named **W1715.2**) is huge with range **A1** to **AN1813** (as of this week) and the range is subject to change every week.

I want to generate a pivot table using this data:

**column label** as **"LT Verification - Planned Week Numbers"** (this is a column name in worksheet)

**row label** as **"LT verification responsible"** (this is also a column name in worksheet)

**values** as **count** of **"ID"** (this is also a column name in worksheet)

**report filter** by **"Build"** and **"Current status"** and **"Type of issue"**

I have a written a code shown below but it only creates a new worksheet with name **PivotTable** but it does not give me any pivot table! Also, the code does not include **report filter** since I do not know how to do it!

Here, I am looking for help to generate a pivot table with the before mentioned requirements.

1) Find the range dynamically as it is changing every week.

2) Pivot Table with the respective column, row labels and report filters and count of value.

3) The pivot table should be on a new worksheet every week

Please have a look at the code below:

```
Public Sub Create_Pivot_Table()

Dim PSheet As Worksheet
Dim DSheet As Worksheet
Dim PCache As PivotCache
Dim PTable As PivotTable
Dim PRange As Range
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim LastCol As Long

'Delete Preivous Pivot Table Worksheet & Insert a New Blank Worksheet With Same Name
On Error Resume Next
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Worksheets("PivotTable").Delete
Sheets.Add Before:=ActiveSheet
ActiveSheet.Name = "PivotTable"
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Set PSheet = Worksheets("PivotTable")
Set DSheet = Worksheets("W1715.2")

'Define Data Range
LastRow = DSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
LastCol = DSheet.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
Set PRange = DSheet.Cells(1, 1).Resize(LastRow, LastCol)

'Define Pivot Cache
Set PCache = ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create _
(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:=PRange). _
CreatePivotTable(TableDestination:=PSheet.Cells(2, 2), _
TableName:="PRIMEPivotTable")

'Insert Blank Pivot Table
Set PTable = PCache.CreatePivotTable_(TableDestination:=PSheet.Cells(1, 1), TableName:="PRIMEPivotTable")

'Insert Row Fields
With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PRIMEPivotTable").PivotFields("LT verification responsible")
 .Orientation = xlRowField
 .Position = 1
End With

'Insert Column Fields
With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PRIMEPivotTable").PivotFields("LT Verification - Planned Week Numbers")
 .Orientation = xlColumnField
 .Position = 1
End With

'Insert Data Field
With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PRIMEPivotTable").PivotFields("ID")
 .Orientation = xlDataField
 .Position = 1
 .Function = xlCount
 .Name = "Names"
End With

'Format Pivot Table
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PRIMEPivotTable").ShowTableStyleRowStripes = True
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PRIMEPivotTable").TableStyle2 = "PivotStyleMedium9"

End Sub
```

I have also included the image of the final pivot table that I wish to have. (I have applied the report filters, hence the small pivot table or else it is very huge)

[image: Required Pivot Table]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it like this...

```
Public Sub Create_Pivot_Table()

Dim PSheet As Worksheet
Dim DSheet As Worksheet
Dim PCache As PivotCache
Dim PTable As PivotTable
Dim PRange As Range
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim LastCol As Long

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
'Delete Preivous Pivot Table Worksheet & Insert a New Blank Worksheet With Same Name
On Error Resume Next
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Worksheets("PivotTable").Delete
Sheets.Add Before:=ActiveSheet
ActiveSheet.Name = "PivotTable"
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Set PSheet = Worksheets("PivotTable")
Set DSheet = Worksheets("W1715.2")

'Define Data Range
LastRow = DSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
LastCol = DSheet.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
'Set PRange = DSheet.Cells(1, 1).Resize(LastRow, LastCol)
Set PRange = DSheet.Range("A1").CurrentRegion

'Define Pivot Cache
Set PCache = ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create _
(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:=PRange)

'. _
'CreatePivotTable(TableDestination:=PSheet.Cells(2, 2), _
'TableName:="PRIMEPivotTable")

'Insert Blank Pivot Table
Set PTable = PCache.CreatePivotTable(TableDestination:=PSheet.Cells(5, 1), TableName:="PRIMEPivotTable")

'Insert Row Fields
With PTable.PivotFields("LT verification responsible")
 .Orientation = xlRowField
 .Position = 1
End With

'Insert Column Fields
With PTable.PivotFields("LT Verification - Planned Week Numbers")
 .Orientation = xlColumnField
 .Position = 1
End With

'Pagefield
With PTable.PivotFields("Build")
 .Orientation = xlPageField
 .Position = 1
End With

With PTable.PivotFields("Current status")
 .Orientation = xlPageField
 .Position = 1
End With

With PTable.PivotFields("Type of issue")
 .Orientation = xlPageField
 .Position = 1
End With

'Insert Data Field
With PTable.PivotFields("ID")
 .Orientation = xlDataField
 .Position = 1
 .Function = xlCount
 .Name = "Names"
End With


'Format Pivot Table
PTable.ShowTableStyleRowStripes = True
PTable.TableStyle2 = "PivotStyleMedium9"
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: why if you already created and `Set PTable` you are not using it ? why use such a long line like `With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PRIMEPivotTable").PivotFields("LT verification responsible")` instead of `With PTable.PivotFields("LT verification responsible")` ?

Comment: @Shai Rado +1 for pointing that out. Yeah that's the way to refer to the pivot table if properly defined. I was lazy to change the whole code. I have edited it as per your suggestion. Thanks. :)

Comment: @sktneer This code is running without an error but only creates a tab named **PivotTable** but no pivot table is generated.

Comment: Where is the data located on W1715.2 Sheet? The code is using Set PRange = DSheet.Range("A1").CurrentRegion, which assumes that the headers are in row1 starting from A1.

Comment: @sktneer: The header starts from A1 in W1715.2 Sheet

Comment: @sktneer: Thank you so much for the help! I am taking Shai Rado's code but included the **report filter** code from yours.

Comment: @sktneer: I missed one point which I realized now when I am running the report! The worksheet **W1715.2** we used to create the Pivot table. But as it is updated every week, a new work sheet gets added to the workbook **W1716.2**. And this new week I want to create the pivot table using the new worksheet. So, the `DSheet` ishould be dynamic. Can you please help me out with this as well?

Comment: If there is only one sheet in the workbook which is named like W17*, to set the data sheet dynamically you can loop through all the sheets and have a condition like If ws.Name Like "W17*" Then Set DSheet = ws.